# Find the area of the region enclosed by the curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I am having some difficulty with this problem:

Find the area of the region enclosed by the curves.
$$4x+y^2=12,x=y.$$

So, the intersecting points I found were $-6$ and $2$.

$$\int\limits_{-6}^2 \frac{\sqrt{12 - y^2}}{4} dy - \int\limits_{-6}^2 y dy$$

I'm not sure how to solve this, any help please.

Comment: Have you tried doing this in terms of $x$, that might be easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In this case it is more convenient 
to consider

\begin{align} 
f_1(y)&=3-\tfrac14\,y^2
,\\
f_2(y)&=y
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
S&=
\int_{-6}^2\!\int_y^{3-\tfrac14\,y^2}\!dx\,dy
=
\left. 3y-\tfrac1{12}y^3-\tfrac12 y^2\right|_{-6}^2
=\tfrac{64}3
.
\end{align}

Comment: A double integral nice. How did you get $3-\tfrac14\,y^2$ ?

Comment: I get the rest of the integration, just don't know how you got that initial value.

Comment: @craz1001: just solve $4x+y^2=12$ for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s add up tiny rectangles of widths along the $x$-direction and infinitesimal height $dy$.

The two curves are defined as $x=y$ and $x=\frac14(12-y^2)$. Therefore, the width of each rectangle is $$\frac{12-y^2}{4}-y$$

That gives the infinitesimal area $$dA=\left(\frac{12-y^2}{4}-y\right)\,dy$$ We can see that we’re adding up rectangles from $y=-6$ to $y=2$, so we just have to evaluate

$$\begin{align}
A &=\int_{-6}^{2} \left(\frac{12-y^2}{4}-y\right) \, dy \\
&= \frac14 \int_{-6}^{2}\left(12-y^2\right)\, dy -\int_{-6}^{2} y\,dy \\
&= \frac14 \left(12y-\frac13y^3\middle)\right|_{-6}^{2} - \left( \frac12y^2\middle)\right|_{-6}^{2}
\end{align}$$

Can you handle it from there?

You were on track *except for* taking the square root.

Comment: Ahh yes I did take the square root, thanks @Chase !

Comment: @craz1001 If you find answers helpful, consider up-voting them and/or giving the $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The area below the $x-$ axis is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-6}^{3} \sqrt{12-4x} dx - \frac{1}{2}6 \times 6.
\end{eqnarray*}
The area above the $x-$ axis is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{2}^{3} \sqrt{12-4x} dx + \frac{1}{2}2 \times 2.
\end{eqnarray*}